# How to build docker image from Vuejs application and push to Nexus repository through GitLab CI/CD?

Tags: docker, vue.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have Vuejs application that needed to build in order to push into Nexus as a Docker image.All the Vuejs contents stores on GitLab repository.

**The pipeline is simple with these stages**

1. **setup** (get the info from pipeline)
2. **build** (npm install and npm run build)
3. **create docker image** (this will perform docker build with Vue application)
4. **push image to Nexus**

I'm using GitLab-runner with docker executor and I've created Dockerfile which contains the required packages for run npm, docker.

However with all these steps, I noticed that gitlab ci will pull docker image every time the new stages begin. So it would break my pipeline into pieces and I can't build a docker image from built Vuejs app also can't push image to Nexus.

Anyway to slove this problem? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is true - in Gitlab (other than in e.g. `Jenkins`), each Job runs with a cleaned, newly checked out repository. Generated artifacts are not automatically transfered from one Job to the next.

That makes it sometimes hard to build connected pipelines, but it is not impossible.

For your use-case, I'd suggest to boil down the pipeline to two steps:

1. **Build**: Setup & Build Project
2. **Release**: Docker Build & Push to Nexus

After the **build** step, you can then use [Gitlab's Artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts) to transfer the build-output / build-artifacts (probably the `build` or `dist` folder?) or whatever else you need in your `Dockerfile` from Step 1 to Step 2.

Comment: Thanks! but actually I've switched to Shell executor and founded that all the concerns were gone! Anyway, the Gitalb's Artifacts is really helps in the part of building Vue project.

Comment: Hi I can't use docker in my vue.js project due to access issues to where docker is located. Is there way we can create docker image without using ```docker build``` from vuejs application? For example, for a java application we have used jib to create docker image and skopeo to push. Is there any such tool or plugin available for vuejs (to be used in gitlab ci/cd?)

Comment: @Rajesh2389 That is actual not a gitlab-related question. Gitlab-CI is just a task runner - so you can install and use whatever tool you want to create docker images.  I 'm actually not familiar at all with other tools to build docker images, but my guess is that it will work with any of them. I suggest you open another thread with that question, I am sure there are a lot of people here that can help you. :)